# SSRS-Access is denied while running this reports in Chrome

Tags: reporting-services

I am facing one problem while running the report in web url of ssrs, it is working fine with IE but not in chrome. Also some users access it fine and some users can't through IE. In call the cases we are getting below mentioned:

Error:

> "Access is denied.
>
> Description: An error occurred while accessing the resources required
>   to serve this request. You might not have permission to view the
>   requested resources.
>
> Error message 401.3: You do not have permission to view this directory
>   or page using the credentials you supplied (access denied due to
>   access control lists). Ask the web server's administrative to give you
>   access"

Please help on the same.

Comment: Try with running the browser as "Run as Administrator".

Comment: Users can not access the same in IE as well, anything else we can do apart from running it as administrator?

Comment: Any help on the same ?

Comment: Do the reports run locally in tool (which are not running in both the browser)?

Comment: Reports were deployed on server and running fine on the same but when I run this report on my system(different PC) with below URL :http://10.XXX.XX.XX/Reports_LALSERVER1/Pages/Folder.aspx it is not working , its showing above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

Check following things in your report manager:

1. As per your error message `Error message 401.3...` (it says you don't have access, check if your account is added to security/permission list of report/folder)
   Try:
   Before opening the report directly, try to access the parent folder of the report (if you have access - to check report is not main reason of issue).
2. Check the `data source` configuration of report, are you able to test the connection (you should be getting like `connection tested successfully` if all set correctly)? If you have configured with Windows authentication, are the different servers in same domain?

Comment: By using Mozila firefox to open the report url, it is asking for username and password of the server where I deployed the report. I want to open that report link without asking the credentials on another system.